# Shutting down remote computer

Tags: vb.net

I have seen alot of these, but nothing that works with my situation, or works for me.

I am trying to shutdown/restart remote computers.

This is my first attempt

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-r -m \\" & ServerName.Text)
```

Above did not work. It opened a cmd window for a short time then closed. No reboot happened.

What I THINK the issue is, it needs a username/password. I know how to do this is batch, but not VB.

This is my batch file that does works

```
Set /P pinghost=Enter Server IP address: 'This would be the textbox information

net use \\%pinghost% /user:domain\user password
shutdown /f /r /t 0 /m \\%pinghost% /c
```

**Edit**
After doing some more research I found something like the below that 'should work'

```
Process.Start("cmd", "net use \\" + RemotePC1.Text + "\IPC$ password /USER:domain\username & shtudown /r /f /t 01 /m \\" + RemotePC1.Text)
```

Have also replaced the + with & with no change.

When doing the above, in the CMD window I get error:

> '/f' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: I would assume in a LAN?

Comment: @436f6465786572 its a Intranet and/or LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the below code. Thanks for everyone input

```
Dim command As String = "/C ""net use \\" & RemotePC1.Text & "\IPC$ password /USER:domain\username & shutdown /s /f /t 01 /m \\" & RemotePC1.Text & "\"""

        Process.Start("cmd", command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to register your user on the remote PC, using local policies GPE.

**Instructions:**

1. Log in with an administrator account and connect to the remote computer that needs to be enabled for shutdown
2. Open the Group Policy Editor utility. Press the "Ctrl" and "R" keys to launch the "Run" command prompt, type "gpedit.msc" in the provided text field and hit "Enter."
3. Expand the following folders on the left pane's tree directory "Computer Configuration," "Windows Settings," "Security Settings," "Local Policies" and click on "User Rights Assignment."
4. Locate the setting named "Force shutdown from a remote system," on the right pane, under the "Setting" column, and double-click on it. A list displays the users that are allowed to shutdown the remote computer.
5. Add a user account or group to be allowed to shutdown the system remotely. Click on the "Add User or Group..." button, click "Advanced," click "Find Now," select a user account or group from the list, click "OK" to confirm the selection, then click "Apply" and "OK" in the "Properties" window.
6. Locate the "Shut down the system" setting on the right pane and perform the same steps to add a user account or group to be allowed to shut down the system remotely.

Comment: That may work, but there are over 1000 remote computers I would have to do it on. The goal is so users can just hit a button, rather than having to log into said servers to shut them down.

Answer (score 0):

[PSShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) should do the trick assuming you are domain admin.

Comment: Unfortunately, PSTools is blocked on our servers